# How to validate Email Id in android?

Tags: android

I had implemented email validation in my app but problem is that app was accepting local domain part of more than 64 character and when I write ..nnn..@gmail.com app was accepting this also and also As per the RFC 3696 specification #section 3, period (".") may not be used to start or end the local part, nor may two or more consecutive periods appear.

Please help me out

```
private boolean isValidEmail(String email) {// validation for email Id
    boolean isValid = false;
    String expression = "^[\\w\\.-]+@([\\w\\-]+\\.)+[A-Z]{2,255}$";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(expression, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(email);
    if (matcher.matches()) {
        isValid = true;

    }
    return isValid;
}
```

Comment: I need to write local-part not to exceed more than 64 characters

Comment: Try this awesome validation library https://github.com/thyrlian/AwesomeValidation

Answer (score 6):

The Android SDK has a built-in regular expression for checking Emails.

[Patterns JavaDoc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Patterns.html#EMAIL_ADDRESS)

```
Matcher matcher = Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email);
return matcher.matches();
```

Comment: This answer should have way more votes. It's specifically targeted for Android and does not repeat the same answer as the other ones.

Answer (score 4):

try this code. Return true if email is valid.

```
android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public final static boolean isValidEmail(CharSequence target) {
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(target)) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(target).matches();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
String expression = "[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-z]+\\.+[a-z]+";
```

Comment: but when I write ..aa..@gmail.com app was accepting

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class EmailValidation {
private Pattern pattern;
private Matcher matcher;

private static final String EMAIL_PATTERN = 
    "^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@"
    + "[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";

public EmailValidation() {
    pattern = Pattern.compile(EMAIL_PATTERN);
}

public boolean isValidate(final String hex) {
    matcher = pattern.matcher(hex);
    return matcher.matches();
  }
}
```

Comment: but when I write .. and 64 character of local domain part it was excepting

Comment: This is working :)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest an easy solution among all these answer

```
public static boolean isEmail(String email){
  return android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(inputData.trim()).matches()
}
```

Read [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Patterns.html) documentation about Patterns.

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest you checkout this library for android client side validation

https://github.com/ragunathjawahar/android-saripaar